# Connecting R to Hive on a Remote Server

Tags: java, r, hadoop, hive

I am trying to connect RStudio to data in Hive that I am accessing through Hue on a remote server.

This is my current code:

```
 options( java.parameters = "-Xmx20g" )
 library("DBI")
 Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_131')
 library("rJava")
 library("RJDBC")
 drv <- JDBC("org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver",
            c(list.files("C:/Users/xxx/Desktop",pattern="jar$",full.names=T),
              list.files("C:/Users/xxx/Desktop",pattern="jar$",full.names=T)))
```

I downloaded the Hive JAR files to my desktop and the xxx is the correct file path. Everything up to here runs fine in RStudio.

However, when I run the following line:

```
 conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:hive2://IP ADDRESS", "usrnm", "password")
```

In which the IP address, username, and password are all correct, I experience the following error:

```
 Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],  : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/thrift/TBase
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you do not have the missing jars/libraries .
Thus it is unable to find the TBase class.

Add the `hive-exec-x.x.x.jar` and see if it works fine for you.

Check this link
http://snacktrace.com/artifacts/org.apache.hive/hive-exec/1.1.1/org.apache.thrift.TBase

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thank you. I downloaded this jar and ran again. Now I am getting the following error:      Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],  : 
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/facebook/fb303/FacebookService$Iface. Do you have an idea what this could be?

Comment: Have you ensured to add all required libraries/jars to your classpath too?

Comment: @Grunvaldskaya Bitva :  If the answer provided solved your query,you can mark my answer as correct with the green arrow, and ask you new question in a new thread.